# How to select and copy log and messages in Kile in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, kile

I am a beginner with Kile and I wonder how should I do to select the log message through the mouse cursor from the box "Log and Messages"

[image: Log and Messages]

Only appears a hand on the mouse pointer. Why can not select anything? What must I do to select the log to search on google?

Comment: Open the file where the latex document is located. Select "all files" option and find the "document-name.log" file. This log file can be opened and viewed in kile. This also contains all necessary processes done, errors, warnings, etc..

Comment: @Leucippus That sounds like an answer for me, so post it as one :).

Comment: @Leucippus If you click on the little arrow at the far left of the 'Log and Messages' bit, you get a drop-down menu. The first item allows you to view the log file. If the errors are listed under the 'Output' bit, you can select text there. Or you can switch to the 'Konsole' bit and type `kile <name of your document>.log' or whatever.

Comment: @cfr It also seems that the "output" button (order of buttons across the top is "log and messages", "output", "Konsole", "preview") once clicked allows for cut-n-paste of log-file information. There does seem to be a button, of green colour, along the side that is marked "view log file" which allows for cut-n-paste. There are many ways to obtain the log-file data set, which is a good thing to know.

Comment: @Leucippus Yes, that's what I said, isn't it? About the 'Output' bit. That and 'Konsole' let you select and copy text. ('Konsole' lets you paste, too, of course.) I don't have a green button. Just a grey arrow. But it probably depends on your desktop theme or something.

Comment: @cfr I just found it interesting. It does depend on the version of Kile, Ubuntu version/Windows. Until this question I had not looked at a log-file.

Comment: @Leucippus Ah... you haven't lived! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help Leucippus and cfr, but decided to leave the Kile and migrate to alternatives like Sharelatex and Overleaf that let you work with version control and collaboratively on the web.